# É possível trocar os pacotes já instalados de "dependencies" para "devDependencies" apenas trocando de linha?

Tags: npm, yarn

Aqui um exemplo do arquivo `package.json`, instalado utilizando o comando 
`npm install <nome> --save-dev`:

```
{
"dependencies": {},
"devDependencies": {
"bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
"cross-env": "^5.2.0",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
"jquery": "^3.3.1",
"node-sass": "^4.9.3"
}
}
```

Se eu apenas mudar manualmente desse jeito, fica algo errado? Fora de alguma convenção, ou pode deixar de funcionar alguma coisa mais pra frente?

(desconsiderar a funcionalidade dos pacotes, são só para exemplificar):

```
{
"dependencies": {
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
},
"devDependencies": {
"bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
"cross-env": "^5.2.0",
"jquery": "^3.3.1",
"node-sass": "^4.9.3"
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, [você pode mover os pacotes](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/using-a-package.json#specifying-dependencies) de suas *dependencies* e *devDependencies* editando o arquivo *package.json* da forma como você descreveu. Só tomaria cuidado ao fazer isso para evitar qualquer erro de digitação (ex: no seu exemplo, você copiou uma vírgula desnecessária ao final da linha, logo antes de fechar as chaves de *dependencies*: `"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",`

Para ser mais seguro, usaria o comando tradicional:

```
npm install module --save-prod
```

Para fazer o inverso (salvar como *devDependency*):

```
npm install module --save-dev
```

Comment: Verdade, esqueci a vírgula. Mas quanto a sua dica de usar --save-prod ou --save-dev eu havia tentado mais cedo e ele não faz a alteração. Tive de desinstalar o pacote antes e baixá-lo todo novamente com a opção correta.

Comment: Estranho, acabei de testar aqui com os comandos e funcionou (ele moveu o pacote de um para o outro). Meu `node` está na versão `8.10.0` e meu `npm` na versão `5.6.0`

Comment: Deve ser versão então, quando fiz isso, o node estava na versão 5.6 eu acho. Fábio, posso emendar uma outra pergunta pertinente? Se meu projeto já tem a pasta `node_modules` no `.gitignore`, qual a usabilidade dessa opção `--save-dev`? Em que caso ela faz diferença? Obrigado.

Comment: a idéia do `--save-dev` é de que você (ou qualquer outro desenvolvedor que venha a trabalhar no projeto) consiga instalar módulos necessários apenas para a fase de desenvolvimento, em sua maquina local ou ambiente de CI (ex: modulos de testes, como `ava`). Esses módulos não serão instalados em seu ambiente de produção. Tendo eles no package.json permite que qualquer um, ao clonar o projeto, apenas precise rodar `npm install` para começar a desenvolver

Comment: Essa parte eu entendi. Mas o que impede de eu subí-los para a produção. Nada correto? Ele serve apenas de `demonstrador` pelo que entendi. Quem realmente `olha` o que vai para produção e `seleciona` é só o `.gitignore` no caso de quem usa `Git`, isso? Muito obrigado pelo seu tempo.